Im trying to use swiperjs along with barbajs but ends up with inconsistent outcome
I'm workiong on a website that uses barba.js for page transitions and swiper.js as a slider on selected pages. Problem is when barba.js is working swiper.js sometimes (oftenly) doesn't load all images. If I referesh a page after that, everything is loaded properly.
I'm using simple trasnition with gsap.
This is my import section and barba.init
import barba from "@barba/core";
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import jquery from "jquery";
export default window.$ = window.jQuery = jquery;

barba.init({
  transitions: [
    {
      name: "default-transition",
      leave(data) {
        return gsap.to(data.current.container, {
          opacity: 0,
        });
      },
      enter(data) {
        return gsap.from(data.next.container, {
          opacity: 0,
        });
      },
    },
  ],
});

This is a beginning of HTML body
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="text-center refreshOne">
      <h2>Refresh your day...</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<main data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="home">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
...

I would appreciate any info that would direct me in the right direction.
